# How to draw solution curves in the phase plane for a system using nullclines

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the nonlinear system: {dx/dt = 2x − 2y   dy/dt = −x^2 + y

(a) Show algebra work to find the two equilibrium points of this system. (b) Find the Jacobian
matrix J(Y0) evaluated at each equilibrium point. (c) Are the equilibrium points hyperbolic or
not? Why or why not? (d) For the equilibrium point(s) that are hyperbolic, use the Jacobian matrix
to classify those equilibrium point(s) (as saddles, real sinks, real sources, spiral sinks, or spiral sources). This
is ”linearization” (a.k.a. application of the Hartman-Grobman Theorem). Show work and/or explain how you
got your answers. (e) Use nullclines to help you draw, by hand, representative solution curves in
the phase plane for this system (NOT the vector field) for −1 ≤ x ≤ 2 and −1 ≤ y ≤ 2. I’m NOT looking
for perfection, just “pretty good”. In other words: (i) Are your solutions crossing the nullclines correctly and
going in the right directions? and (ii) Do your equilibrium points look like the way you classified them from
part (d)?

I have answered every part of this question except for part e already. For a the equilibrium points are (0,0) and (1,1). which leads to a Jacobian matrix of J(x,y) = {2, -2} , {-2x, 1} which allows you to easily plug in the equilibrium points. Part C both equilibrium points are hyperbolic because they have eigenvalues with a nonzero real part. In part D the origin is a source because it's eigenvalues are greater than zero and for the point (1, 1) I wasn't quite sure because one eigenvalue is above 0 and one is below (does that make it a saddle point?). However, the part that is really tripping me up is part e if someone has a good way of explaining how to draw solution curves and how to answer part e I would very much appreciate it.